# Is there any possibility to make credential providers work with ARM-based Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, credential-providers

There are working examples for Windows Credential Provider on Intel-Based like x86 and x64, but I couldn't find any possibilities to work it for ARM/ARM64. Builds are OK, but I am slightly confused about copying files to correct directories. Because there are a lot!

```
SyChpe32
SysArm32
System
System32
SystemApps
System Resources
System Temp
SysWOW64
```

I tried to copy build files to these directories and put registry values to exact places and had no luck.

These are sample codes that you can use to build a similar process.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/credential-provider/
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/security/credentialproviders

Comment: cp can be in any directory on your choice

Comment: My all other CP's in the System32. For x86 and x64, they are working. But even though I build it for ARM/ARM64, it is not working.

Comment: Every CP register self clsid and here path to self dll. So you can place dll at any location

Answer (score 2):

I am able to work it through!

When I build helpers libraries with **ARM64** (not with the ARM) and copy to **System32** directory! Everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: *System32* is the directory that contains the system-native binaries, irrespective of the true bitness of the OS. I'm convinced that *The Old New Thing* has a blog post on this topic, but I'm failing to find it at this time.

Comment: How you built your libraries did the trick. Credential providers are **generally** in System32 sure, but if registered properly can be anywhere.
I explained this more thoroughly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71413981/2567602).